# Find a general solution to a second order linear partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, wave-equation, characteristics

I have an equation of the form

$$
\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + a \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \right) \phi + \eta \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + c_1 \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \right) \left(\frac{\partial }{\partial t} + c_2 \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \right) \phi = 0,
$$

where $\eta$ is a positive constant and $c_1>c_2$.

When $\eta \to 0$ we have the general solution using the method of characteristics

$$
\phi= \phi_0 (x - a t),
$$

and when $\eta \to \infty$ we have the general solution using the method of characteristics

$$
\phi= \phi_1 (x - c_1 t) + \phi_2 (x - c_2 t).
$$

Is it possible to find a general solution for $\phi$ without having to take a limit of $\eta$ (possibly using the method of characteristics or a Fourier transform)?

Comment: Your equation is $(L_{0} + L_{1}L_{2}) \phi = 0$. You have the solutions for both $L_{0} \phi = 0$ and $L_{1} L_{2} \phi = 0$. Now you just take the product $$\phi = \phi_{0}(x - at) [\phi_{1}(x - c_{1} t) + \phi_{2}(x - c_{2} t)] \tag 1$$ Just so you know, when you have a 'product' of operators, the solution is a sum (as you have shown with $\phi_{1}, \phi_{2}$) while if you have a 'sum' of operators, the solution is a product which is what $(1)$ is showing.

Comment: @mattos If you set $\eta=1$  in the original equation, the solution (1) doesn't satisfy the original equation (unless I've made a mistake in my algebra). Also, do you have a reference for the product of operators vs the sum of operators?

Comment: What would make you think about using the Fourier transform? Is there a similar question you have seen use this which you can link?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames The original equation describes the motion of a wave, and so I think using Fourier transforms could be a possible approach.